# Improve the endless loop

Tags: matlab

```
 [st,message] = system(cmd);
 while st~=false
 [st,message] = system(cmd);
 end
```

In the case where `st` is always false , I stuck in a loop for ever which is't good !
how could I improve that by adding a threshold a break ?

any suggesion ?

Thanks,

Comment: Add a counter and set it limit. `while st~=false && counter < limit` and increment `counter` inside of loop.

Comment: a way to use beak ? I wouldn't to use && count<threshold but may be go out from loop

Comment: Not sure what you are asking about. If you want to get out of the loop use a regular `break;` command http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html

Answer (score 2):

```
count = 1;
while st~=false && count < 1000
 [st,message] = system(cmd);
 count = count + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t=rem(now,1);
[st,message] = system(cmd);
while st~=false
[st,message] = system(cmd);
if  rem(now,1)-t > 0.0001
   break
end
end
```

Since the condition is not that important to you that you consider `break` after a while, you can also try this,

```
[st,message] = system(cmd);
if st~=false
   pause(2);
end
[st,message] = system(cmd);
```

Comment: what's the 0.0001 ? threshold ?

Comment: @lola Yes, a threshold. Actually `rem(now,1)` measures time, but to be honest, I don't know it does!

Comment: @lola, you want to leave the loop after a while even if the condition doesn't match?

Comment: no, I wanttgo leave the loop when st=false but in the same time I don't want to loop forever if there is a problem